# I making a multiplayer unity game for this reason i used photon pun but i try PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom("room"); dont work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon, photon-pun

Sorry for turkish language

[this the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVrKT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom` takes four parameters: 3 required, 1 optional. Along with specifying the name of the room, (which you did, "oda1"), you must also pass a `RoomOptions` instance (which contains settings about the room), and a TypedLobby instance (a lobby is a set of rooms).

Creating a RoomOptions instance is easy enough in Photon, you can just use `new RoomOptions()`. This is where you will set any room-specific information, such as the maximum number of players per room, via the `MaxPlayers` property. Pass this as the second parameters into JoinOrCreateRoom

The TypedLobby instance is a bit more complicated, but as you are just starting out, using `TypedLobby.Default` is good enough. This just means that it'll use the default lobby for your game. Set this as the third parameter.

The fourth parameter, `string[] expectedUsers`, is entirely optional. It is only used when multiple people will join a room at once, like using a party-up system. Do not pass anything right now.

The final code should look something like this:

```cs
public void JoinCreate() {
  RoomOptions options = new RoomOptions();
  options.MaxPlayers = 10; //set however many players you would want here

  PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom("oda1", options, TypedLobby.Default);
}
```

I highly recommend reading the error messages, seen at the bottom of the box that appeared when hovering over the code in question. I also recommend taking the time to [read the documentation](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_network.html#a5cb3a7c033f38f09408b8f5eebd24293), and if you have, include what you have tried / searched before making a post here.